# Trying to find a good way to control servos at different speeds using johnny-five.io

Tags: loops, arduino, raspberry-pi, servo, johnny-five

I am currently trying to figure out a configuration in controlling servos connected to Arduinos using Nodebot johnny-five.io hosted on an RPi. My main goal is to make a hexapod from scratch; I don't like the idea of kits because it's all cookie cutter code and parts that you put together and it's more or less a remote controlled car where you didn't learn anything.

I just learned the basics about servos (which I'm selecting servos over stepper motors). And unfortunately, as a default, servo speed cant be controlled via PWM, only position. So the way around this is to create a loop that increments the servo 1 degree (or more) at a time with an X ms delay in the loop until the servo has reached the desired position. Now, this is fine and all if you're only controlling one servo at a time or X amount of servos at a time for moving to one set position to another. But I'm shooting for a fluid motion here; I want one leg to start moving before another leg has stopped. True fluidity in motion, to accomplish this, I would need an infinite loop that would check on input states set by control commands that the API would receive.

The problem here is that while loops are not asynchronous. So, I need to find a way to kick a loop off that sets the different servos at different speed ranges and different positions, and at the end of the loop checks for new input state updates. And I need to do this without creating a memory leak.

One way would be to create a set of dependency scripts that worked asynchronously for each of the servos (3 servos per leg, 6 legs, 18 servos thus 18 mini dependencies), but I'm not sure if that would be too much overhead or put much strain onto the RPi.

Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple servo class and give each instance its own speed and starting position using an 'update' method. Use a longer delay to have the servo move slower. In the main loop you can continuously check for some input, tell the servos to move if necessary, using the update method.

```
#include <Servo.h>

class HexapodLegServo
{
  Servo servo;         // Servo instance
  int pos;             // Position/angle of the servo
  int delay_millis;    // 'Delay' between each update
  long prev_millis;
  int degree_change;       // Angle increase each update
  int start_pos;       // Position to start at
  int pin;             // Pin servo is connected to

  public:
    HexapodLegServo (int whichPin, int delayMillis=15, int startPos=0)
    {
      pin = whichPin;
      delay_millis = delayMillis;
      start_pos = startPos;
      degree_change = 1;
     }

     void attachToPin()
     {
       servo.attach(pin);
       setStartPos();
     }

     void setStartPos()  // Set initial position of the servo
     {
       servo.write(start_pos);
       pos = start_pos;
     }

    void update()  // Servo sweeps from end to end, and back
    {
      if (millis()-prev_millis > delay_millis)
      {
        prev_millis = millis();
        servo.write(pos);
        pos += degree_change;

        if ((pos <= 0) || (pos >= 180))
        {
          degree_change *= -1;  // Start moving in the reverse direction
        }
      }
    }
  };

// Main script
const int BUTTON = 4;  // Button on pin 4
HexapodLegServo right_leg(9);
HexapodLegServo left_leg(10, 30, 90);

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(BUTTON, INPUT_PULLUP);  // Using a button to tell servos when to move

  right_leg.attachToPin();
  left_leg.attachToPin();
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(BUTTON) == LOW)  // If button is pushed (can be any type of input)
  {                                // update the position of the servos continuously 
    right_leg.update();
    left_leg.update();
  }
}
```